# Returning a Value from a Suitelet popup to a Client Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Looking for some assistance on how to return a value from a Suitelet popup to a client script.

I have a client script triggered by a field change which executes the suitelet:

```
var url = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', 'customscriptnbi_weeklytimesheet_suitelet','customdeployso_lineselectionpopupsuitele',false);
var resp = window.open(url,'_blank','width=300,height=300,titlebar=0,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=0,scrollbars=0');
```

On the Suitelet, how can I "write" the response back to the client script:

```
    if (request.getMethod() == 'GET' ) {
        var form = nlapiCreateForm('Select Sales Order Line',true);
        form.setScript('customscriptnbi_weeklytimesheet_slet_cs')
        form.addSubmitButton('Set');
        response.writePage(form);
    } // END 'GET' METHOD
    else {


        response.write('<html><body><script>window.parent.close(); </script></body></html>');
    } // END 'POST' METHOD
```

any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using a client script on your Suitelet.  You can put a custom field on the record where the client script that calls the Suitelet is deployed at.

Then in you client script that is attached to the Suitelet, you can do window.opener.nlapiSetFieldValue(,);

Comment: When triggering 
`window.opener.nlapiSetCurrentLineItemFieldValue('timeitem','memo','This memo is a test')`
from the client script, I'm getting an error:
`window.opener.nlapiSetCurrentLineItemFieldValue('timeitem','memo','This memo is a test')`
However `window.close()` is successfully closing the window.
Context is logged as `userinterface`

Comment: Whats the error?  Have you tried using nlapiSetLineItemValue?

Comment: Yeah. It's almost like nlapi functions are not visible... Could be that it's a Weekly Timesheet which is a little unusual. However, normal commands work on the actual client script on the record.

Comment: Weird, not tried it with Weekly Timesheet but I was able to use it successfully for other record types before.